# Why the gzipped file uploaded to the azure blob container with a custom file extension is being downloaded as .gz via the generated sas?

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-blob-storage, gzipstream

Here is my method on generating the SAS:

```
        private string GenerateSasBlob(BlobClient blobClient)
        {
            BlobSasBuilder sasBuilder = new BlobSasBuilder()
            {
                BlobContainerName = blobClient.GetParentBlobContainerClient().Name,
                BlobName = blobClient.Name,
                Resource = "b",
                StartsOn = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow,
                ExpiresOn = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMonths(1),
                Protocol = SasProtocol.Https,
                ContentType = "mygzip"
            };
            sasBuilder.SetPermissions(BlobSasPermissions.Read);

            return blobClient.GenerateSasUri(sasBuilder).ToString();
        }
```

I thought that by specifying the ContentType fixes it however the generated sas still downloads as .gz instead of the expected .mygzip.

Though looking into side-by-side the contents inside of the compressed file is the same but what I need is it should be .mygzip when downloaded. Any idea on how?

Comment: `however the generated sas still downloads as .gz instead of the expected .mygzip` - you mean the file is downloaded as `myfile.gz` instead of `myfile.mygzip`?

Comment: yes, you are correct

Comment: Changing the content type is not going to help. Content type is for the user agents (like browser) to determine how to deal with the blob content. How are you downloading the blob using SAS URL? Are you using it in your code or just pasting The SAS URL in a browser?

Comment: it is meant to be used via email notification (embedded as hyperlink) so more on using it via browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering you would want the blob to be downloaded with a different extension (mygzip instead of gz), essentially you would want the blob to be downloaded with a different name.

In that case, the response header you would want to overwrite is [`Content-Disposition`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.sas.blobsasbuilder.contentdisposition?view=azure-dotnet#azure-storage-sas-blobsasbuilder-contentdisposition) instead of `Content-Type`.

Your code would be something like:

```
private string GenerateSasBlob(BlobClient blobClient)
{
    var newBlobName = blobClient.Name.Replace(".gz", ".mygzip");//Change the extension here in the name
    BlobSasBuilder sasBuilder = new BlobSasBuilder()
    {
        BlobContainerName = blobClient.GetParentBlobContainerClient().Name,
        BlobName = blobClient.Name,
        Resource = "b",
        StartsOn = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow,
        ExpiresOn = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMonths(1),
        Protocol = SasProtocol.Https,
        ContentDisposition = $"attachment; filename=\"{newBlobName}\""
    };
    sasBuilder.SetPermissions(BlobSasPermissions.Read);

    return blobClient.GenerateSasUri(sasBuilder).ToString();
}
```

Now when a user clicks on the SAS URL, the blob will be downloaded with "mygzip" extension.

More information on Content-Disposition header can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition.